# if the output is float value then use tofixed(2) else avoid .00

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I have some case about toFixed(2);

```
var abc = 20;
var xyz = 20;
var sss = ((parseInt(abc) / parseInt(xyz));
if (!isNaN(sss))
{
   console.log(sss);
}
```

output: 1

```
    var abc = 20;
    var xyz = 19;
    var sss = (parseInt(abc) / parseInt(xyz));
    if (!isNaN(sss))
    {
       console.log(sss.toFixed(2));
    }
```

output: 1.05

```
var abc = 20;
var xyz = 20;
var sss = ((parseInt(abc) / parseInt(xyz));
if (!isNaN(sss))
{
   console.log(sss.toFixed(2));
}
```

output: 1.00

The problem is that I want to avoid the trailing digits if the result is an integer. I only want the `toFixed(2)` format when the result is a float. How can I do that ?

Example:

```js
var num = (1.01).toFixed(2)
console.log( num) //output ok 1.01
// But When
var num = (1.00).toFixed(2)
console.log( num) //expected output 1
```

I having the issue will you guys please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check with `Number.isInteger`:

```js
const show = (a, b) => {
  const div = a / b;
  if (Number.isNaN(div)) {
    return;
  }
  const toDisplay = Number.isInteger(div) ? div : div.toFixed(2);
  console.log(toDisplay);
};

show(19, 20);
show(20, 20);
show(22, 20);
```